# Printer drivers for epson wf-3640

Tags: printing, epson

Epson offers what appears to be the print drivers, including wireless connect,for the wf-3640 printer. (got it on sale from tigerrdirect.com retail shutdown) Although all but iscan install saying it need epkowa commponent.  I must admit I am lost.  I am convinced this printer can be setup to work with Ubuntu but I am at the point I need some help/guidance on what to do???? Even after installing all but iscan there is not printer that appears to be installed.

Comment: I've had great luck with HP printers and scanners because HP really supports Linux with `hplip`.  Both for my own sanity and to encourage companys to support Linux, I buy HP. When I've gone cheap, I end up pulling my hair out ans settling for a clunky-kinda solution at best.

Answer (score 8):

This is very late, but for anyone else searching for the driver, it is in the package printer-driver-escpr which can be installed via apt-get or any of the graphical package managers (but not the software center).

Comment: That did the trick on Xubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

worked like a charm for me on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, epkowa is the proprietary scanner driver by Epson. If it says you need the epkowa component (i.e. sane-epkowa back-end), that likely means you need to follow the below guides:
How to install printer component/driver: http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/08/23/how-to-install-epson-wf-3640-all-in-one-printer-drivers-quick-start-scanning-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-linux-easy-guide/
How to install scanner component/driver: http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/08/23/quick-start-with-epson-scanner-for-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-lts-with-iscan-easy-guide/
Hope I was helpful :-)

Comment: This was of no  use at all.  It suggests a path to the drivers but all it says is search for the drivers.  This is an attempt to spread advertizing to users.  There is no substance to this persons offer of assistance.  Was it helpful> NO

Comment: Your welcome for the advice

Answer (score 0):

A very late addition - hopefully somebody will benefit from this.

Above procedure (sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr, then add a printer in GUI) will result in a working printer, however it will not report ink levels, as it seems to create an IPP printer.

If you create a 2nd driver based on URI, enter "dnssd://EPSON%20WF-3640%20Series._ipp._tcp.local/" this will have the same functionality PLUS be able to report ink levels.

Markus

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a driver for a Epson 3540 instead of a 3640 which is what I wanted, but it worked fine for what I needed to print.
Thank you.

Comment: can you edit your answer to include where you got the correct driver? this answer looks helpful, but needs a little more info. thanks and welcome to AskUbuntu!